# Why integer (Number) are saved as Double in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, integer, double

I'm working on a new project and I try to figure out why when Mongoose save my model, instead of having an integer, I got a Double.

Ex. {myId: 12345678} become {myId: 12345678.0}​

My schema contains this:

```
{
 myId: {
  type: Number
 }
}
```

Mongoose version: 5.x
Node: 10.x

Any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Number` schema type is floating point. If you want to store a number as an integer, you can use the [`mongoose-int32`](https://github.com/vkarpov15/mongoose-int32) plug-in:

```
var Int32 = require('mongoose-int32');
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  myId: {
    type: Int32
  }
});
```

If you need 64-bit integer support, use the [`mongoose-long`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-long) plug-in.

Comment: why mongoose itself doesn't give that date type?

Comment: @Ashish I'm also surprised that data type isn't not part of Mongoose itself. Especially as the author of the plug-in is one of the main Mongoose developers.

Comment: Thank you for your message. Meanwhile, I used this library:
`mongoose-long`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-long

It works great too :)

Comment: @Vincent Both work for integers; `mongoose-long` is 64-bit and `mongoose-int32` is 32-bit.

Comment: It's so irony that neither mongodb or mongoose provides int type by default

Comment: It is so sad that we have to use another plugin to get this job done.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I got an error message saying `Invalid schema configuration: `Int32` is not a valid type at path`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of additional npm package overhead, it's recommended to use such getter/setter in the Schema Types.

```
var numberSchema = new Schema({
  integerOnly: {
    type: Number,
    get: v => Math.round(v),
    set: v => Math.round(v),
    alias: 'i'
  }
});
```

Therefore, CRUD operations related to field of `Number` Schema Type will cast to `Int32` in Mongodb.

More info can be found in [Mongoose v5.8.9 Schema Types](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) documentation

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I don't want to use Plugins either.